# Upvote reputation was not added with my Account

Tags: bug, reputation

[image]

See the above Image its my account .Two question upvote reputation not added with my account.But the answer reputation was added.

Any body explain why? and Whats the reason?

Comment: You have hit the reputation cap.

Comment: @PatrickHofman .that 20 reputation count by tomorrow or ignored

Comment: @prasad: As mentioned in the dupe question _Any upvotes you receive after reaching that number no longer award any points_. So it will ignore those reputation.